# Issue with allocating dynamic memory in C

Tags: c

I am trying to allocate dynamic memory for a number of integers in an array, and then fill the array with random numbers. The problem is, if I do this for 5 elements, it works... If I do it for more, it crushes, and I don`t know why. Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
   int i;
    int* arr=generateRandomInts(50);
    printf("Given array:\n");
    show(arr,50);
    return 0;
}

int* generateRandomInts(int n)
{
    int i; int *v;
    v=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        v[i]=rand()%200;
    }
    return v;
}

void show(int *v,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",v[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` change to `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` and put prototype before main or main move to last.

Comment: I actually need this to start from 1, because I am applying in this program the heap sort algorithm... but thank you for pointing that out, now I know that if I want n numbers I should allocate memory for n+1.

Comment: No, it you want `n` numbers you allocate space for `n` numbers.

Comment: You should call the function free to free the memory you allocated with malloc as well. When you allocate memory like you do: int* p = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int)), valid indexing is: p[0], p[1],..., p[n-1].

Comment: If you really *insist* on indexing `v` starting at `1`, then you might want to allocate `n+1` values and just ignore the value at `v[0]`. It seems silly, but if that's what you want... Why the need to start at `1`? If this is part of a larger context where you are given a number in the range `1` to `n` (let's say the value is in `i`), then you would index `v` as `v[i-1]` normally.

Comment: You can use 0-based indexing with `left(k) -> 2 * k + 1` and `right(k) -> 2*k + 2`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to allocate n + 1 positions (that is horrible :P)

Here you have an example i found in the internet that can be useful for you using the heap sort algorithm.

```
/*
 * C Program to sort an array based on heap sort algorithm(MAX heap)
 */ 
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int heap[10], no, i, j, c, root, temp;

    printf("\n Enter no of elements :");
    scanf("%d", &no);
    printf("\n Enter the nos : ");
    for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
       scanf("%d", &heap[i]);
    for (i = 1; i < no; i++)
    {
        c = i;
        do
        {
            root = (c - 1) / 2;             
            if (heap[root] < heap[c])   /* to create MAX heap array */
            {
                temp = heap[root];
                heap[root] = heap[c];
                heap[c] = temp;
            }
            c = root;
        } while (c != 0);
    }

    printf("Heap array : ");
    for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
        printf("%d\t ", heap[i]);
    for (j = no - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        temp = heap[0];
        heap[0] = heap[j];    /* swap max element with rightmost leaf element */
        heap[j] = temp;
        root = 0;
        do 
        {
            c = 2 * root + 1;    /* left node of root element */
            if ((heap[c] < heap[c + 1]) && c < j-1)
                c++;
            if (heap[root]<heap[c] && c<j)    /* again rearrange to max heap array */
            {
                temp = heap[root];
                heap[root] = heap[c];
                heap[c] = temp;
            }
            root = c;
        } while (c < j);
    } 
    printf("\n The sorted array is : ");
    for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
       printf("\t %d", heap[i]);
    printf("\n Complexity : \n Best case = Avg case = Worst case = O(n logn)\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Source: http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-heap-sort-algorithm/

Hope this helps.

Comment: `void main` has undefined behaviour; all you did was that you copied a broken heapsort program from the internet.

Comment: Thank for your comment Antii Haapala.  As I mentioned in my post it is just an example, and answering your question,yes I copied from the internet from the source I mentioned.  I never wanted to take credit of that (that is why I put the source in the post).  About the void main,  I changed to int main() and I put a return 0 at the end, but it does not make any difference in the point of the topic of this question.  Another point is, why you said that is a broken heapsort algorithm?  Did you test it?

Comment: I said the program is broken, not that the algorithm is not broken.

Comment: I forgot to mention.  I know that this code needs some controls.  Ex. if the variable `no` is greater that 10, this code is not going to work (`heap` is declared statically with 10 elements). I think `heap` need to be allocated with `sizeof(int) * no` previous to get each item.
Hope this clarify a little bit that, I know what I am copying from internet, it is not just a copy & paste :)

Comment: Ouch... Sorry, I know what you mean.  The code is fixed and working now.. Thanks for point that :)